# I install XAMPP every day and the next day its gone

Tags: windows-10, localhost, xampp

I installed XAMPP 2 days ago to work on a wordpress site locally.  I left it open and running overnight on accident.  The next morning all of my tabs/browsers/programs were closed (I assumed the power went out in the night? 
 Though now that I think about it, all of my appliance clocks were fine...).  I searched my computer for XAMPP and the folder where it's files are housed is present and the .exe install file is present.  The desktop and start menu options are gone as well as, it seems, the whole program?

I reinstalled, got no errors, it worked perfectly.  Last night I stopped it correctly, closed out all of my tabs.

This morning, its gone again. What am I doing s.th. wrong? Is there some obscure way you have to access this program?

Answer (score 1):

Closing the internet tabs should have no impact on xampp.  From what I remember xampp is not auto start you will have to load the xampp control panel and start your services there.  If the control Panel is already running it should show as an orange icon in the notification area of the task bar.  The file for the control panel is in the root xampp directory ("C:\xampp" on my computer) named "xampp-control.exe".

Open that program and it should load the control panel.  This will allow you to start XAMPP's services.

Please note the control panel does not need to be running in order to use XAMPP it allows you to start / stop services that will continue to run in the background.

As far as the shortcuts disappearing it is odd.  I would be sure to install and restart the computer right after the install.  Without knowing more information about the computer it would be hard to say why the shortcuts are disappearing.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  There was no orange icon running or anything.  I reinstalled, replaced shortcuts, and restarted.  We will see if it happens again tomorrow?  Friday the 13th maybe?  Who knows